# How to write XPath expression to select node name from its value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xpath

I'm trying to write an XPath expression to select the name of a node from its value in "qualities" and then select in "qualityNames" the value inside node whose name has previously captured.

E.g. In "qualities" - got value "4", take name "rarity3" then in "qualityNames" I got node named "rarity3" and take value "amazingrarity"

```
<result>
  <status>1</status>
  <qualities>
    <Normal>0</Normal>
    <rarity1>1</rarity1>
    <rarity2>2</rarity2>
    <vintage>3</vintage>
    <rarity3>4</rarity3>
    <rarity4>5</rarity4>
  </qualities>
  <qualityNames>
    <Normal>Normal</Normal>
    <rarity1>Genuine</rarity1>
    <rarity2>rarity2</rarity2>
    <vintage>Vintage</vintage>
    <rarity3>amazingrarity</rarity3>
    <rarity4>Unusual</rarity4>
  </qualityNames>
</result>
```

I'm doing this in C# (It's a MVC App) and I'd prefer to use XPath because I'm indexing the XML and I haven't found a fastest way to query in-memory technique (this XML file has ~3MB and I'm using IndexingXPathNavigator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the local-name() and text() functions + predicates. For value "4" it will be

```
//qualityNames/*[local-name()=local-name(//qualities/*[text() = '4'])]
```

Tested with http://www.xpathtester.com

Comment: Thanks for edit, @Sphinxxx - did not noticed that trouble with asteriks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to create a dictionary of key/value pairs (assuming the node names are only needed to find matches and aren't important to your code).

If so, you can use the following:

```
var doc = XElement.Parse(@"<result>
<status>1</status>
<qualities>
    <Normal>0</Normal>
    <rarity1>1</rarity1>
    <rarity2>2</rarity2>
    <vintage>3</vintage>
    <rarity3>4</rarity3>
    <rarity4>5</rarity4>
</qualities>
<qualityNames>
    <Normal>Normal</Normal>
    <rarity1>Genuine</rarity1>
    <rarity2>rarity2</rarity2>
    <vintage>Vintage</vintage>
    <rarity3>amazingrarity</rarity3>
    <rarity4>Unusual</rarity4>
</qualityNames>
</result>");

var query = from quality in doc.XPathSelectElements("qualities/*")
            join qualityName in doc.XPathSelectElements("qualityNames/*")
            on quality.Name equals qualityName.Name
            select new { Key = quality.Value, Value = qualityName.Value };
var qualities = query.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
var quality3 = qualities["3"];
// quality3 == "Vintage"
var quality4 = qualities["4"];
// quality4 == "amazingrarity"
```

EDIT: example of how to cache this dictionary

```
// add reference to System.Web dll
public Dictionary<string, string> GetQualities()
{
    // assuming this code is in a controller
    var qualities = this.HttpContext.Cache["qualities"] as Dictionary<string, string>;
    if (qualities == null)
    {
        // LoadQualitiesFromXml() is the code above
        qualities = LoadQualitiesFromXml();
        this.HttpContext.Cache["qualities"] = qualities;
    }
    return qualities;
}
```

Comment: Yes.. the question was answered but my problem still exists! :) How can I construct this dictionary and share with entire application, without build in every request? (not exactly 'how' because you already showed) Where should I build this dict?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you asked

> ```
>         var rarity3ValueInQualities = xml.SelectSingleNode("/result/qualities/rarity3").InnerText;
>         var rarity3ValueInqualityNames = xml.SelectSingleNode("/result/qualityNames/rarity3").InnerText;
> ```